# using case and contains in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column `x-property` which has values `xxx-abc`, `xxx-def`, `123`, `mno` ....etc.

I have another column `isx`.

I wish to update table to fill up column `isx` such that if the row in `x-property` column contains `xxx` then add `abc`, else add `xyz`.

I do not have SQL full text search in my table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `contains` use `like`, because from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187787.aspx):

> CONTAINS is a predicate used in the WHERE clause of a Transact-SQL SELECT statement to perform SQL Server full-text search on full-text indexed columns containing character-based data types.

This is your query:

```
update
    table
set
    isx = 
        case
            when x-property like '%xxx%' then 'abc'
            else 'xyz'
        end
```